# What can be done to fix a decorator whose root class requires the decorator instance?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, decorator

I am refactoring a piece of software to try to make it more testable/DI friendly and to make it more extensible. The original code relied on inheritance, but I was thinking that a decorator would be a more flexible design because I want the end user of the component to be able to insert layers below some of the layers I am creating.

However, I have run into a wall because some of the code in what was the base class passes `this` into some of the methods. Using inheritance this wouldn't be a problem because `this` would reference the top layer type, but I am having trouble trying to work out how to make this work with a decorator. Here is an example:

```
public interface INode
{
    bool IsReadOnly { get; }
    void DoSomething();
}

public class Node : INode
{
    public Node(ISomeFactory someFactory)
    {
        if (someFactory == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("someFactory");
        this.someFactory = someFactory;
    }

    private readonly ISomeFactory someFactory;


    public bool IsReadOnly { get { return false; } }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // Some implementation code here

        // This factory doesn't get an instance of the decorator type
        // when it is in use - this is a problem
        var someInstance = someFactory.Create(this);

        // More code here...
    }
}

public class LockableNode : INode
{
    public LockableNode(INode node, ILockingService lockingService)
    {
        if (node == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("node");
        if (lockingService == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("lockingService");

        this.innerNode = node;
        this.lockingService = lockingService
    }

    private readonly INode innerNode;
    private readonly ILockingService lockingService;

    public bool IsReadOnly { get { return lockingService.IsReadOnly; } }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
       if (this.IsReadOnly)
           throw new InvalidOperationException("Node is read-only");

       this.innerNode.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Then my factory does something like this:

```
var someFactory = new SomeConcreteFactory();
var lockingService = new LockingService();

var node = new Node(someFactory);
var lockableNode = new LockableNode(node, lockingService);
return lockableNode;
```

The problem as outlined by my comment is that some places in the code that I am trying to decorate, the current object is being passed as a parameter to other methods and I need an instance of the decorator object when it is in use and the current object when it is not. Short of re-implementing the code that passes `this` into the factory in the decorator class, is there something that can be done to fix this?

Comment: Let's say base node is decorated by more than one decorators, then which one of them should be passed to this factory?

Comment: The outside most instance is the one I am after, same as would be the case with inheritance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In conclusion, in my case the answer was to use inheritance. I am sure the decorator pattern has its uses somewhere, but adding functionality to a domain object that makes cross-member calls and that passes references to itself to other objects isn't it, especially if you don't have control over when or how other references or cross-member calls will be inserted into the code in the future.

I found this other post that had a couple more ideas that I didn't try though:

[A problem when using the decorator design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859469/a-problem-when-using-the-decorator-design-pattern)

Answer (score 0):

Make the actual `doSomething` a method that needs the decorated object as a parameter:

**Node**

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    this.DoSomethingWith(this)
}
public void DoSomethingWith(INode it)
{
    // ...

    var someInstance = someFactory.Create(it);

    // ...
}
```

**LockableNode**

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    this.innerNode.DoSomethingWith(this);
}
public void DoSomethingWith(INode it)
{
    this.innerNode.DoSomethingWith(it);
}
```

*Edit:* Of course, you will have to change the interface as well.

```
public interface INode
{
    bool IsReadOnly { get; }
    void DoSomething();
    void DoSomethingWith(INode it);
}
```

Comment: I ended up doing this with one of the main methods just to get it working in the first place. However, the design is still way too frail because it is easy to forget to implement something somewhere. Realistically, anything more than a simple cascade is too complex. This is an open source project with several hundred users and the API should be intuitive to use. For now, I have reverted back to inheritance as it seems to cover all the bases, but I am still open to other ideas.

Comment: I take that back, this is not too complex. I will give it more consideration.

Comment: If you want to simplify the creation of decorators you could move part of it to an abstract decorator. The usage should still be as simple as before